# Array pointer always points to NULL

Tags: c

Im trying create a linked list in an array of nodes. When I try to update the pointer for arrTab->h_table[index] to the address of newNode, The address  points to newNodes address. But when I try to add to a list that exists in the array, the pointer always points to NULL instead of the previous value in memory. Basically the arrTab->h_table[index] head of the linked list does not update to the address of newNode.

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node* next;     
  int          hash;     
  s_type     symbol;
} node_t;


struct array {
  int      cap;    
  int      size;       
  n_type** h_table;
};



int add_to_array (array* arrTab, const char* name, int address) {
  if(s_search(arrTab, name, NULL, NULL) == NULL){
    s_type *symbol = (s_type*) calloc(1, sizeof(s_type));
    symbol->name = strdup(name);
    symbol->addr = addr;
    n_type  *newNode = (n_type*) calloc(1, sizeof(n_type));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->hash = nameHash(name);
    newNode->symbol = *symbol;
    int index = newNode->hash % arrTab->cap;
    if(arrTab->h_table[index] == NULL){
      arrTab->h_table[index] = newNode;
    } else {
      newNode->next = arrTab->h_table[index];
      arrTab->h_table[index] = newNode;
    }
    //
    arrTab->size++;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

struct node* s_search (array* arrTab, const char* name, int* hash, int* index) {
  int hashVal = nameHash(name);
  hash = &hashVal;
  int indexVal = *hash % arrTab->cap;
  index = &indexVal;
  s_type *symCopy = arrTab;
  while (symCopy->h_table[*index] != NULL){
    if(*hash == symCopy->h_table[*index]->hash){
      return symCopy->h_table[*index];
    }
    symCopy->h_table[*index] = symCopy->h_table[*index]->next;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot say for sure why *the pointer always points to NULL*; there is not enough code. Consider posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The posted code however presents few problems to address.

First, it leaks memory like there is no tomorrow:

```
symbol_t *symbol = (symbol_t*) calloc(1, sizeof(symbol_t));
```

allocates some memory, and

```
newNode->symbol = *symbol;
```

copies the contents of that memory to the new location. The memory allocated still exists, and continues to exist after the function returns - but there's no way to get to it. I strongly recommend to *not* allocate `symbol`, and work directly with `newNode->symbol`:

```
newNode->symbol.name = strdup(name);
newNode->symbol.addr = addr;
```

The `hash` and `index` parameters to `symbol_search` seem to be planned as an out parameters. In that case, notice that the results of `hash = &hashVal;` and `index = &indexVal;` are invisible to the caller. You likely meant `*hash = hashVal` and `*index = indexVal`.

The biggest problem comes with `sym_table_t *symCopy = symTab;`.

`symTab` is a pointer. It points to an actual symbol table, a big piece of memory. After the assignment, `symCopy` points to the same piece of memory. Which means that

```
symCopy->hash_table[*index] = symCopy->hash_table[*index]->next;
```

modifies *that piece of memory*. Once the search is completed, the `hash_table[index]` is not the same as it was before the search. This *could* be a root of your problem. In any case, consider

```
node_t * cursor = symTab->hash_table[*index];
```

and work with this cursor instead.

As a side note, a search condition `*hash == symCopy->hash_table[*index]->hash` is strange. Every node in a given linked list has the same hash (check how you add them). The very first node would produce a match, even if the names are different.